# How do I specify the interface language for CKEditor (jquery version)?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

My code atm is this simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('textarea').ckeditor();
});
```

It works flawlessly, I just need to add one more thing: I need to specify the interface language (localisation). I tried reading the CKEditor help site, but it isn't very helpful.

Can anyone tell me where and how do I add any code to specify the language?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('textarea').ckeditor({language: 'de'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but check this out:

http://www.sayopenweb.com/ckeditor-faq/

---

Q.
How do i set language for CKEditor for achieving localization?

A.
Use language property for setting the language of CKEditor. By using this property CKEditor menu’s and labels will display
the localized language.

```
CKEditor.replace('divcomponentid', {
        language: 'ja'
})
```

And if you are using custom config file for creating CKEditor instance use,

```
CKEditor.editorConfig = function(config) {
    language = "ja";
};
```

Even one can use javascript variable to set language file to make localization option dynamic.

Comment: for custom config file, use config.language = "ja"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom config file for creating CKEditor instance try this.

[image: config]

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way to set up your language to `CKE 4` editor :

```
 1. Go to config.js -> 
 2. Then change this line in config.js ->
 3. config.language = "en"
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a multilingual portal and it is possible to change the language of whole interface. To change the language of the editor I am using `ajax`, to get the currently selected language. Here is the code which I added in `config.js`:

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    var strLanguageName = "en";
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false, cache: false });
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/remotemethods/getCurrentLang",
        data: "xml",
        success: setLanguage,
        error: onError
    });
    function setLanguage(data) {
        strLanguageName = jQuery(data).find("lang").text();
    }
    function onError(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { }
    config.language = strLanguageName;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more example (based on **[CKEditor5](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html)**):

```js
let theEditor;

ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
    // The language code is defined in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1 standard.
    language: 'sk'
  })
  .then(editor => {
    theEditor = editor;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.2.0/classic/translations/sk.js"></script>
<textarea name="content" id="editor">This is some sample content.</textarea>
```