# How set language ckeditor by html attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I can language set into javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   CKEDITOR.config.language = "fr";
</script>
```

I had a idea set lang do it like this?

```
<textarea name="name" id="name" cols="30" rows="10" data-lang="fr"></textarea>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I specify the interface language for CKEditor (jquery version)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049020/how-do-i-specify-the-interface-language-for-ckeditor-jquery-version)

Comment: @ArunPJohny This question is totally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following one should help you (+ [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g84te/)):

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( evt ) {    
    var editor = evt.editor,
        element = editor.element,
        lang = element.data( 'lang' );

    if ( lang )
        evt.editor.config.language = lang;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('textarea').ckeditor({language: 'fr'});
```

Comment: No, I wrote `CKEDITOR.config.language = "fr";` its work. I want send a language to CKEDITOR with html attribute