# CKEditor5 set language

Tags: reactjs

I tried Editor on my first project (React)
I copied basic code on their guidelines, and tried to change language.
In their guideline, it is possible to use "CKEdit.config".
placeholder is working but, language is not working.
How can I solve this?

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

function CK(){
    
       return (
            <div className="Ckcontainer">

                <CKEditor
                    editor={ ClassicEditor }
                    config = {{
                        placeholder : "please your question, here",
                        language : 'de'
                   }}
          
                    onReady={ editor => {
                        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                    }}

                    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        const data = editor.getData();
                        console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                    }}

                    onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
                    }}

                    onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
                    }}
                />
            </div>

        );

}
export default CK;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this. I wanted to set the language to Turkish.

```
import '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/translations/tr';

  <CKEditor
    editor={ClassicEditor}
    data={newNote}
    onReady={editor => {
      
    }}
    config={{
      toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'blockQuote', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', 'insertTable', 'undo', 'redo'],
      language: 'tr',
      //'link', 'imageUpload','tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'mediaEmbed', '|',
    }}
    onChange={(event, editor) => {
      setNote(editor.data.get());
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this issue is because of our double Moustache tags `{{ }}`

Try this:

```
        <CKEditor
            editor={ ClassicEditor }
            config = {
                placeholder : "please your question, here",
                language : 'de'
           }
  
            onReady={ editor => {
                // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
            }}

            onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                const data = editor.getData();
                console.log( { event, editor, data } );
            }}

            onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
                console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
            }}

            onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
                console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
            }}
        />
```

Here are some similar solutions:
[How do I specify the interface language for CKEditor (jquery version)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049020/how-do-i-specify-the-interface-language-for-ckeditor-jquery-version)